# What happens when we define class name as String?

Tags: java, string, class

Given a class shadowing a builtin class like String:

```
class String {
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
}
```

String is not a keyword, but still, the above program gives a runtime error. Why is that?

Comment: Well, what is the error???

Comment: String is already the name of a class. The String class. This, to me, assumes you want to override that class.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Error is: Error: Main method not found in class String, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: @MichaelPickett Yea, String is already a class name, i know. But can i override that?

Comment: @MichaelPickett Ok, i was just learning. I won't gonna use it in real-time app. So, what happens when we extend Application class?

Comment: It turns into a JavaFX project. Check the answer below though, they have more info on what happens when you use a standard java class name as your custom class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad thing happens, when you define a class with the name **String**  you are shadowing a `java.lang.String` Class
that means every declared object must use the full-qualified name `java.lang.String` if it refers to a "normal String" other than that will point to your defined one..

example is the code you write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

if that is the only class you have, then the compiler will complain since the entry point for an application will never be found...

you will be need to define explicit the argument by doing

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {

}
```

this is a very nice pitfall that will break your neck, all the most because the classes in the java lang doesnt need to be imported,your code must be carefully writen and is pretty much error prone..

That code will compile but in any decent code analyzer you will get a lot of complains and rename suggestions..

I will follow that way too, and suggest never name your classes like standart java classes...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the `main` method is 'special' in that it is the entry point of the program. The arguments of the program are specified to have a variable number of *Java*'s `java.lang.String`s, not your String class. Your string class is the closest one to the class as it's the current class, so Java uses your String class in the `main` arguments when JVM expects the Java's String, thus leading to the error. You can prevent this by using the fully qualified name of Java's String:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, user-defined String class will have more priority over Libraray String class?

Comment: Yes, because it's the closest one as it's the current class @NickSilicon